# When i try to free memory using xerces "visual studio 2010" my project crash

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xerces

I'm working in a project and I use the xerces library. When I try to delete a pointer my project crashes.

Here is the source code:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& target, const DOMString& s)
{
char *p = s.transcode(); // method from xerces
target << p;
delete [] p;

return target;
}
```

This method works fine in Visual Studio 6 (I'm trying to build in 2010).

Comment: It's probably using a different C runtime library with a different heap. As Evan says you should use the functions it provides to do the deletion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [xerces docs](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classXMLString.html):

> NOTE: The returned buffer is dynamically allocated and is the
>   responsibility of the caller to delete it when not longer needed. You
>   can call XMLString::release to release this returned buffer.

It seems that xerces allocates the buffer **not** with `new[]` (perhaps `malloc` or some custom allocator). The only way to guarantee that the buffer safely gets deallocated is with: `XMLString::release`

Comment: thanks for your answer,i work with xerces-c_1 i didn't found a release method in XMLString.